# Firefox iframe body does not match iframe's height

Tags: css, firefox, iframe

There are a lot of posts about the actual iframe's height, but for me my iframe's heigh is fine. There's more of an issue with the document inside it not filling up. There's a gap at the bottom and it's transparent, so it looks like the document is filling up the top 95% of the iframe only.

Answer (score 0):

On your inner document, try setting the css to `html { height: 100%; }`.

Comment: can you provide your html and css?